# "You can learn the basics in three lines or so" - Is that correct?

Tags: meaning

> You can learn the basics in three lines or so.

I want to say that you can learn the basics by reading a few lines of something (e.g. a text). Is that phrase correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct but it is extremely informal and usually reserved for spoken conversations. "Or so" tells the listener that it may not be *exactly* three lines but it should be something around that length.

An alternative exists that moves the "or so" next to "three":

> You can learn the basics in three or so lines.

This can be more clear if there is a large amount of detail after "three or so".

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think it is correct. This is what I would say:

"Having read the first three lines, you will have grasped the basics."

Comment: That's good, but you're changing the style a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No but you already provided most of the solution:

"You can learn the basics by reading a few lines only"

or

"You can learn the basics by reading only a few lines"